# Terms for specific kind of water taps

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

There are two types of taps in my house, and both of them are suitable for cold, hot or mixed water.

The difference is one kind has ONE knob and the other kind has TWO.

The one-knob tap (for kitchen) controls hot and cold water together. When the knob is rotated to the left, hot water flows out, meanwhile right means cold water, and center means mixed water.

The two-knob tap (for bathroom) controls hot and cold water separately. One is for hot water and the other is for cold water.

OK, so are there two specific terms or phrases for two kinds of taps?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Uh, "one-handle faucet" and "two-handle faucet".

Comment: (Or "single-handle faucet".)

Comment: According to http://www.build.com.au/types-and-styles-taps and http://www.bathrooms.interiordezine.com/fixtures/types-of-faucets/ , it sounds like both are "mixer taps" (i.e. there's only one spout for the mixed hot and cold water, instead of two separate spouts). The dual-knob type might be known as a "crosshead tap", "spoked tap", or "knob tap" (depending on what shape it is) and the single-lift type might be known as a "lever tap". Like any specialized field, I'm sure there's much, much more terminology that I'm not familiar with!

Comment: @NickWeinberg - Aside from "mixer", I've never heard any of those terms in the US, and I doubt that many plumbers have either. http://www.homedepot.com/p/KOHLER-Forte-Single-Hole-Single-Handle-Low-Arc-Water-Saving-Bathroom-Faucet-in-Vibrant-Brushed-Nickel-K-10215-4-BN/100626527?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal1_rr-_-206786189-_-100626527-_-N

Comment: Presumably, what you describe as a *one knob tap*, as well as its knob controlling the temperature, requires another knob to control the flow?

Comment: @WS2 - The "single-handle faucet" typically is controlled by a sort of lever which is lifted to turn on the water flow and rotated to the left or right to control temperature.  (Surely similar controls must exist in the UK?)

Comment: @WS2 sorry that's a lever, not a knob.

Comment: I remember the day when they all had two handles. Prior to that, they all had one: cold water only. And you had to pump it manually. Then before that, ladies hauled it in buckets from the nearest creek.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes they do [here](https://www.victorianplumbing.co.uk/modern-single-lever-basin-tap-dty305?campaign=googlebase&gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIy86O7qLb3wIVBpztCh1BnApTEAQYAyABEgJeP_D_BwE) for example.

Comment: @KeyuGan If it only has one knob and no lever how does it turn off? Does it give cold water first then gradually warmer water as you turn it? And is the flow constant, just varying in temperature?

Comment: @HotLicks Yes of course they do - we have them in our house. I'm not sure why I wrote that comment in 2016 - must have been having a dim day. But what we don't do is call them "faucets" - completely foreign word to us. Where on earth does it come from?

Comment: @WS2 - It's been a "faucet" all my life.  Did you look at Etymology Online?

Comment: The OED indicates "a tap for drawing liquid from a barrel - dialect and US". (I've never in all my years ever heard any UK person say "faucet" - but then I'm not often around barrels!) It gives the etymology as French - *fausset*. However, though I've lived in France I've never heard the word used there either - and my Concise Oxford Hachette French dictionary has no entry for *fausset*.The normal French word for "tap" is *robinet*.   The OED adds the following clarification.

Comment: *...more fully spigot and faucet...still used in some parts of England, consisting of a straight wooden tube, one end...tapering to be driven into a hole in the barrel, while the other end is closed by a peg or screw...when loosened allows the liquor to flow out through a hole in the under side of the tube. Properly, the spigot seems to have been the tube, and the faucet the peg or screw (as still in Sheffield dialect); but in some examples the senses are reversed, and each of the words has been used for the entire apparatus. In the U.S. faucet is now the ordinary word for a tap of any kind.*

Answer (score 2):

*Single-handled* and *double-handled* (or *one-* and *two-handled*) are the terms you'd look for while buying a faucet, and also refer to faucets with knobs. This is likely what the average customer would search for, but there are more technical terms that exist.

"Single Hole Kitchen faucet" is another term for single-handled faucets, according to [here](http://www.bestkitchenfaucetshub.com/13-types-kitchen-faucets-know/).

One specific type of two-handled faucet is the [compression faucet](http://www.hometips.com/how-it-works/faucets-compression-cartridge.html):

> Compression faucets have two separate handles. When the handle is turned, it raises or lowers a washer or seal that closes against a valve seat at the base of the stem to restrict water flow through the faucet body when you turn the handle off.

Comment: This may be the US term, but the terminology may differ in the UK, where the word *faucet* is not used.

Comment: @choster From what I saw, the only difference is that "tap" is used instead of "faucet". For example: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60818/

Comment: The "compression faucet", also known as a "globe valve", is the standard "old-fashioned" faucet, the same as is used in a "sill cock" or some other stand-alone water valve in traditional (US) plumbing.  Ignoring "gate valve", which is only used for main water cutoff purposes, the other (more modern) scheme is some variation of the "ball valve", where a ball, cylinder, or plate slides against some sort of manifold containing ports that let water through when hole in the sliding piece is oriented with a port.  Pretty much all single-handle faucets use some sort of slider mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The most common terms for one-knob tap and two-knob tab are single handled faucet and double handle faucet. Some people might also call single or double hole; but, that denotes different thing. A faucet with single hole can have double handle or knobs. You seem to be interested about tabs or faucets. I found [Faucetsreviewed](https://faucetsreviewed.com/best-kitchen-sinks/) helpful. Have a look. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Thomas, welcome to EL&U. You seem to use "tap" and "tab" interchangeably - is there a reason for that? Note also that "the most common terms" are country-specific: "faucet" in **not** commonly used in most Commonwealth countries. See [here for BritE preference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kitchen+tap%2Ckitchen+faucet&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckitchen%20tap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckitchen%20faucet%3B%2Cc0). Also, your link doesn't seem to work - I recommend deleting it, as it's not probably relevant for EL&U.